# Type of usage/accuracy

Tags: american-english, british-english

As the boy tames the wild bird, it evokes pleasure in him away from his hardship in society; **the bird is bettering us here.**

verb
gerund or present participle: bettering

```
improve on or surpass (an existing or previous level or achievement).
```

Bird (animal) substituting human failure: that is what it means.

Can this clause be reduced as **the bird bettering us here** and use a comma instead of a semi-colon.

Or is that  wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the bird is bettering us'.

Comment: @KateBunting I thinking "bettering" is being used to mean "make better" in the sense of improve, while its normal meaning is "surpass/exceed/outdo" (ie. "the bird is beating us")

Comment: The bird is bettering....? I don't think this is the right choice of word.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "X is bettering Y" tends to be taken to mean that X is scoring higher than Y in some competition.  Attempting to use it to mean that X is causing Y to become better would not be the normal interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

By "bettering" it is meant that the presence of the bird is improving us. It does this by distracting the boy from his current hardships.

If you were to say "..the bird 'Betters' us" it might be similar but seems tortured and may not be understood

From Wiki; "A gerund is the present participle of a verb..."